# Which character can work as "tick" (US "check-mark") in documents under Ubuntu and Windows?

Tags: windows, fonts

I need to use a character for "tick" in LibreOffice documents that will display OK in Ubuntu and Windows. Character 252 (or thereabout) in Wingdings works in Windows but obviously this character wouldn't be displayed properly on systems lacking the fontset (eg my Ubuntu system).

Can Wingdings be installed in Ubuntu? That would solve my problem of transferring documents between my Windows and Ubuntu systems.

Is there another way to solve this? eg an anternative font that looks like a "tick" and works across setups. I suppose if there is no other way, I could use the square root character, which is in the basic fontset.

Comment: Hmmm. Could you include a screenshot of the character you are talking about? When you say tick, I am imagining a backtick, i.e. "`"

Comment: I mean the character that looks like a square root. See https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=isch&hl=en&source=hp&biw=1024&bih=514&q=tick&gbv=2&oq=tick&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_l=img.3..0l10.3683.4352.0.5072.4.4.0.0.0.0.186.436.3j1.4.0...0.0.p_I8o6eK-Js

Comment: Also http://devbinder.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/install-wingdings-font-on-ubuntu.html may work for installing wingdings.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unicode has a character for the tick (check-mark) character:

✓

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick_(check_mark)

You can find this character using the search function of the "Character Map" application.  But do search for "check mark" and not "tick".

Comment: https://live.gnome.org/Gucharmap on Ubuntu

Comment: This actually works as long as I use a unicode font of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Around here, we'd call that a check-mark. My suggestion would be to either use an image of a check-mark or the built-in check-mark bullet point, if that would work for you.

Comment: This difference between American and British English is very confusing, particularly as check-mark also refers to the X-like symbol. I just noticed that symbol appears next to these comments!

Answer (score 0):

Webdings are available in Ubuntu. In Libre Office use:

Insert > Special Character > (Font) Webdings > (Select the Special Character you want)
The checkmark symbol is also available in this character set.

Comment: But Webdings is not on Windows by default so it is not really a solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To insert a check mark: In word type “3” without quotes, highlight and right click the 3. Select Character and in the window that opens up, select the font tab and  under Family type “dingbats” without quotes and hit the return key. In spreadsheets highlight all the required cells and right click, select Format Cells, select the font tab and under Family type “dingbats” without quotes and hit the return key. Each time you type 3 in one of these cells a check mark will appear.
3 and 4 will give check marks, 7 and 8 will give crosses.

Download ufonts.com_zap-dingbats-normal.tff from ufonts.com/search/dingbats/11
To install fonts in linux:
 Copy .ttf  to usr/share/fonts/truetype then compile fonts: sudo fc-cache -fv

In Windows10:
 Right click the file and select install then re-boot.